# How to manually configure NodaTime IWeekYearRule correctly?

Tags: c#, nodatime

I am wrapping NodaTime for use in our software, and to be future-proof I thought I'd set up IWeekYearRule according to Bcl DateTimeFormat, like this:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var weekRule = WeekYearRules.FromCalendarWeekRule(
    culture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
    culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Here in Norway we're following the following settings:

```
CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek
DayOfWeek.Monday
```

However, much to my surprise, when I checked the week number of the following two dates, [kalender.no](https://www.timeanddate.no/kalender/?year=2018&country=18) disagrees:

```
2018-12-31: week 53 of 2018 (kalender.no says week 1 [implied: of 2019])
2019-01-01: week 1 of 2019  (kalender.no agrees here)
```

However, if I use WeekYearRules.Iso, they both return "week 1 of 2019", which is the correct one.

I have a bunch of questions but let's focus on the most immediate one:

How can I write the code to "future-proof" this part of the library, so that when we start rolling out the software into more parts of the world, it will calculate week numbers correctly out of the box, according to the local culture?

Or is this just not possible, because the culture information doesn't contain this?

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad) example that demonstrates NodaTime behavior (sorry for not including a [mcve] to begin with):

```
void Main()
{
    "-------------- ISO --------------".Dump();
    Test(WeekYearRules.Iso);

    "-------------- BCL --------------".Dump();
    Test(WeekYearRules.FromCalendarWeekRule(CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday));
}

public static void Test(IWeekYearRule rule)
{
    var date = new LocalDate(2018, 12, 31);
    $"{date}, {rule.GetWeekOfWeekYear(date)} in {rule.GetWeekYear(date)}".Dump();

    date = new LocalDate(2019, 1, 1);
    $"{date}, {rule.GetWeekOfWeekYear(date)} in {rule.GetWeekYear(date)}".Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
-------------- ISO --------------
mandag 31. desember 2018, 1 in 2019
tirsdag 1. januar 2019, 1 in 2019
-------------- BCL --------------
mandag 31. desember 2018, 53 in 2018
tirsdag 1. januar 2019, 1 in 2019
```

*(and just to be clear, the ISO output is the correct one for Norway)*

This is NodaTime 2.4.4, Windows 10, .NET 4.7.2.

---

And here's a LINQPad example without using NodaTime:

```
void Main()
{
    var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nb-NO");

    var calendarWeekRule = culture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule.Dump();
    var firstDayOfWeek = culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek.Dump();

    var date = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31);
    $"{date.DayOfWeek} {date}, week {culture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, calendarWeekRule, firstDayOfWeek)}".Dump();

    date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);
    $"{date.DayOfWeek} {date}, week {culture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, calendarWeekRule, firstDayOfWeek)}".Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
FirstFourDayWeek
Monday
Monday 31.12.2018 00.00.00, week 53
Tuesday 01.01.2019 00.00.00, week 1
```

The Monday there is in the same week as week 1 of 2019, and is counted as week 1 in 2019 here in Norway, so the first of the two dates should really have been:

```
Monday 31.12.2018 00.00.00, week 1
```

Comment: Does .NET itself give different results, when using those rules? (Basically, I'm trying to work out whether this is a bug in Noda Time, or a bug in your expectations of Norway's rules. It may well be that Norway's rules can't be correctly represented in regular .NET.)

Comment: I stopped using .NET for this kind of thing many years ago because it is hopelessly wrong on this. The Iso rule in Nodatime works correctly, the Bcl does not. Let me fire up LINQPad and reproduce it using just .NET and see what happens.

Comment: Same issue with normal .NET code, I guess Nodatime just wraps .NET then? In a different product here at work we rolled our own week calculation because of this problem with .NET, many years ago, but in the new project I'm working in we have NodaTime in some framework classes so I thought I would use it, but perhaps I'm still not escaping .NET here.

Comment: I added linqpad examples for both Nodatime and pure .NET, they both exhibit the same problem when using the culture information. `WeekYearRules.Iso` is the one that works correctly.

Comment: Basically what I'm afraid of is that for instance in the US, `WeekYearRules.Iso` produces the incorrect values, according to this page - https://savvytime.com/week-number/united-states/2018 - 31st of December 2017 is part of week 1 of 2018 whereas Nodatime, with Iso, is saying week 52 for this case (and probably incorrect week numbers for all of 2017). So Iso is correct for Norway, but wrong for the US, which means I can't simply use Iso either.

Comment: Now, to be clear, I would be more than happy with just a way for me to keep using Nodatime, but also be able to configure it properly, so if there was a way to construct different types of rules that corresponded to different parts of the world, I could reduce the problem on my side to figuring out which countries used which rules, as we start to roll out to more and more countries, but right now I'm not sure I can even use Nodatime for this, and have to just roll my own calculation for the various scenarios.

Comment: My gut feeling on this is that you need some "YourBusinessRules" wrapper at some point anyway, to handle this "use different rules depending on country" . This logic seems to be out of the NodaTime lib scope. But @JonSkeet may have a more relevant insight on this matter... I think that ISO rule could be use for United States, it shouldn't be "wrong" *per se* to me (as a non-US person), but of course it might not be what your actual customers expect.

Comment: US uses weeks that starts on Sunday, which is not what the ISO standard does. A different question would be if I should actually expect Nodatime to support this situation at all, or if I just need to look elsewhere. It would probably a very nice project to have on Github, assuming nobody else has made it, which in 2019 is probably rather unrealistic :) Doesn't seem to be a nuget package that would add this either.

Comment: Fundamentally, if you use `WeekYearRules.FromCalendarWeekRule`, you should expect to get the same behavior as .NET. It's not that we wrap .NET - it's that I implement the same rules. It's intended for a route of "We're currently using .NET rules, and want to migrate to Noda Time without any changes." If you want ISO rules, use `WeekYearRules.Iso`, which can't be emulated with the .NET rules. Basically Noda Time supports whatever specific rules you ask it to follow, but it doesn't know which rules any particular locale follows.

Comment: I was hoping Nodatime would "do the right thing" (tm) and fix the mess that is in .NET, but I suspect this problem is much larger than either libraries in terms of knowing what the right thing is. I feel that perhaps a list of culture codes that map to settings or rule objects might be what we need then.

Comment: Is it possible to configure NodaTime to produce US week numbers then? Or is the webpage I linked to above wrong perhaps? https://savvytime.com/week-number/united-states/2018 - I can't seem to figure out how to get it to calculate week 1 (of 2018) for 31st of December 2017 while at the same time calculating week 52 for 23rd of December 2018.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: I'm afraid I don't know where I'd get definitive information about that. I'd expect that it's very *likely* that the .NET rules would cover that, but I haven't tried it myself. Of course, you could always implement `IWeekYearRule` yourself if nothing in Noda Time works out of the box - but I'd definitely try to find definitive sources first. (And in that case we'd probably try to add an implementation for a future release.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering suggests that `CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay` and `DayOfWeek.Sunday` might do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately with those settings, 31st of December 2017 is reported as week 53 of 2017 and 1st of January 2018 is reported as week 1 of 2018, even though they are part of the same week. Is this actually how some countries do it, or is this just a bug somewhere? The same thing happens when I use the Norwegian settings, if the first week of the year starts at the end of the previous year, it is incorrectly counted as week 53 in that previous year, instead of as week 1 of the next year. I say incorrectly but if it is by design then my expectations are incorrect.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: That's in-keeping with the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendarweekrule?view=netframework-4.7.2. It sounds like it would be feasible to implement an `IWeekYearRule` that did what you wanted, but I don't *think* we have anything out of the box. (If it's always a matter of changing "week 53" to "week 1" you could probably piggyback on top of another `IWeekYearRule`, but I'm not sure that assumption is valid.)

Comment: I understand that it may be documented to behave like this, I'm just wondering if there's any country that actually does this. But anyway, this all just sums up my fear, I cannot rely on anything 3rd party to get this right, I will have to build out a set of rules and configurations for each country as we roll it out.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: That seems like a valid conclusion, I'm afraid :( I'm happy to add more support in Noda Time for any patterns that appear to be common. Feel free to file an issue that you update over time as you encounter the patterns of different countries.